# Calling two identical Classes from one Test Class and comparing results

Tags: java, class, testing, automated-tests

I am currently developing a system that will, hopefully, be used to compare the results of two individual, but identically-named classes. By comparing the two classes, I hope to be able to determine if the outputs from the first classes methods are the same as the outputs from the second classes methods, given the same input parameters.

How would I go about running the same test class on two independent classes, dynamically?

Psudocode example:

If I have a simple test class...

```
class TestClass{
   public int TestMethod(int num){
   int num2;
   TestedClass t = new TestedClass();
   num2 = t.add(num);
}
```

and two identical classes that need to be tested...

```
class TestedClass{
    public int add(int num){
    num = num + 2;
    return num;
}
```

and

```
class TestedClass{
    public int add(int num){
    num = num + 4;
    return num;
}
```

How would I go about running the TestClass with respect to the two different TestedClass, and then saving the result of the tests in some form of collection.

As you can see, the two TestedClass's are identically named and the return types are identical, only the functionality differs slightly. I also do not have access to change the TestedClass's, however I can control where they are located within the program, package etc.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Appeared to have very cleverly missed out a very important piece of information:

I also do not have access to *edit* the TestClass, although, as above, I will know the class/method names and have control over where they are located. The idea is to build something that can dynamically test a class given a copy of the input and correct output (the TestClass and the other TestedClass).

Apologies for the confusion.

**EDIT 2:**
I have access to the tests, ie. I can run them, I just cannot edit them, for example as a few answers suggested.

Comment: You would use fully qualified class name each time you refer to these classes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I have edited the question appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo.bar.TestedClass   c1 = new foo.bar.TestedClass();
baz.plugh.TestedClass c2 = new baz.plugh.TestedClass();
assertEquals(c1.add(42), c2.add(42));
```

*Edit*

You don't need to run the two tests in the same JVM, you can just call the methods, save the output, and compare using any variety of techniques. Or you could scan for classes the same way old JUnit did it and instantiate via `Class.forName("...").newInstance()` and run methods via reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see the edit as to why that won't work.

Comment: @ChrisM So you want to test two classes you can't access, using a test you can't access. Huh. The usecase for which I cannot begin to fathom. If you can't modify the test then you're screwed--a test you cannot change... won't change. What *precisely* are you trying to do? Build a test suite? All test frameworks I know of already let you do this, and even if it didn't, you could scan the test classpath for classes named "Test*" or whatever, or... but I have no idea what you actually want.

Comment: The premise is that a student runs the program, selects from a drop-down list the Exercise name and uploads their own .java file - the program then runs the Students prgogram and compares the output from different methods with the outputs that the master copy has given (using the same inputs). Where the results differ, a customised print-out will appear informing the student of what method contains the error - and letting them know possible solutions. The programs will be from a simple Java 101 class so will be 1 file max.

Comment: I can access/run the files, but cannot edit them, for example to add fully qualified names as per your example.

Comment: @ChrisM So you're building a test suite. You don't need to run them both in the same suite, you just need to compare outputs from two different ones. Trivial scanning can identify tests, running them can be as simple as `Class.forName("foo...").newInstance()` and you can run methods via reflection. This is how old JUnit did it.

Comment: @ChrisM (Wrong button.) There's no reason to run them in the same JVM instance, you can save textual output and compare across runs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Interface declaring the `add` method, and implement the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern to provide different implementations of this interface.

A more advanced way to deal with this is by using an Injection Dependency library, like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to run the TestClass on the two TestedClasses at the same time, it just arranging the jars in the classpath such that the intended TestedClass that should be tested comes first. Hope this helps.

Comment: The tests should be able to performed dynamically, with new test and tested classes being added regularly - so I don't think this is an option?

Comment: Then I think the problem statement is not clear enough. Would it be possible to show the entire "Test" class? I just want to look at how it is able to refer to Tested class.